# How to replace "children:" with another keyword (e.g. "descdendants:")

Tags: javascript, keyword, fancytree

I have a dataset with a hierarchy structure corresponding to the json structure of fancytree, with the exception of "children:" being denoted as "descendants:". I seem to remember that there exists an option to tell fancytree to use another keyword for "children" in the data sets, but cannot find it. Could somebody help me out?

Comment: this is kind of vague.  which version are you using? did you read the docs? what's your structure look like? are you sure if was generated with fancytree (could be a fork of it instead)?

Comment: By looking at the code it seems like it expect to find the `children` property and doesn't support any option to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to convert input data is to implement the `postProcess` callback

```
postProcess: function(event, data) {
  var orgResponse = data.response;

  orgResponse.descendants = orgResponse.children;
  delete orgResponse.children;
}
```

([see also the docs](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialLoadData#howto-handle-custom-data-formats)):

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comments, will use the postProcess to replace the strings

Comment: Then you should accept and/or upvote this answer... ;)